# How to format backend response data with snake_case fields and "magic numbers" in a React/TypeScript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, normalization, normalize

I'm working on a React and TypeScript project, and I'm making several requests to the backend using axios. However, I noticed that the response data is not properly formatted. Specifically, the fields are in snake_case instead of camelCase, and some of them use "magic numbers" like 25, 50, and 75. This is causing issues because some components use snake_case fields, and there is a lot of logic in React components written with these magic numbers (e.g., if conditions).

I have several questions:

1. What is the best way to format data? Should I do it immediately upon
   receiving the response from the backend?
2. Is it okay to write an interceptor that converts all fields to
   camelCase right after receiving the data?
3. Is it necessary to perform a deep conversion to camelCase, or is it
   enough to only convert the first-level object properties?
4. What is the best way to replace magic numbers in fields? Would it be
   okay to use strings instead of numbers (e.g., replace 1 and 2 with
   'user' and 'administrator')? That would make it more readable.
5. How can I make this code performant and minimize the amount of code
   required?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For 1,2 and 3, it depends on how you use those data, do the transformation or not is both fine.

However, since it is a typescript project, you will not be worried about typo issues after the transformation apply (e.g. "The field in this layer is call `user_name` or `userName`?"), the complier will check about that.

But I suggest you to use some validator like [zod](https://zod.dev/), it provide both validation and transformation features that can ensure backend response format is correct.

---

About the **magic numbers** in this case, create an `enum` might be a good choice:

```
const enum UserLevel {
  USER = 1,
  ADMIN = 2
}

// usage
interface UserResponse {
  username: string,
  level: UserLevel
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and for suggesting zod.